# Operating system manufacturers forcing users to use certain applications

Tags: enforcement, operating-system

Some operating systems include applications that the user can't uninstall or even disable; things like gaming applications, map applications, translation applications, photo arrangement applications (not gallery per se), etc.

Is there a movement calling for the eradication of this forcing practice in which manufacturers actively seek to force customers to use certain applications? Is the *Free software movement* the only such movement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly not the case that the only people that care about unbundling applications from the operating system are the free software folks - for example, see the various actions against Microsoft who certainly made it hard to use Windows without Internet Explorer for a number of years ([US case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Microsoft_Corp.), [EU case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Corp._v._Commission)).

On the other hand, I don't believe there is a particular movement focused on this narrow aspect of software freedom - the free software movement don't just want the ability to stop using App A and replace it with App B, but instead the ability to modify App A to the users' needs. I'd argue that the "freedom to run your own apps" probably isn't going to do what you want it to - if the original app makes use of proprietary bits of the lower levels of the operating system (as is definitely the case on iOS and pretty close to the case on Android with Google Play Services), you're not going to be able to get the required functionality. This is why it's important for software to be free "all the way down the stack", not just at the application layer.